# Mathematica: Grokking 'maximal number of evaluations' argument for `NestWhileList`

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am using [NestWhileList](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestWhileList.html) in a situation where it often hits the 'maximum number of evaluations'. After getting some curios results, I took a closer look at how `NestWhileList` reacts to having a maximum number of results specified:

```
Table[{nmax,
   Length@NestWhileList[
     (* f: nesting function *) Identity,
     (* initial state *) 1,
     (* test function *) False &,
     (* m: of arguments for test *) 1,
     (* nmax: max # applications of f *) nmax,
     (* n: extra evaluations *) 1]}, {nmax, 0, 2}];
ToString[TableForm[%, 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"nmax", "output length"}}]]
```

The surprising part is that `nmax=1` is singled out: Here `f` is applied 2 times, while for all other values, it is only applied once:

```
 nmax   output length
 0      2
 1      3
 2      2
```

The 'extra evaluations' seem to be part of the problem. Leaving that option out gives much more reasonable results:

```
Table[{nmax,
  Length@NestWhileList[
    (* f: nesting function *) Identity,
    (* initial state *) 1,
    (* test function *) False&,
    (* m: of arguments for test *) 1,
    (* max: max # applications of f *) nmax]},{nmax,0,2}];
ToString[TableForm[%,TableHeadings->{None, {"nmax","output length"}}]]

Out[123]=    
   nmax   output length
   0      1
   1      1
   2      1
```

My question: does this somehow make sense, or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make sense, and I'm fairly sure it's just a bug. `NestWhile` is similarly afflicted:

```
In[53]:= NestWhileList[# + 1 &, 1, False &, 1, 1, 1]

Out[53]= {1, 2, 3}

In[54]:= NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, False &, 1, 1, 1]

Out[54]= 3
```

Here's a workaround function for `NestWhileList`:

```
myNestWhileList[f_, expr_, test_, m_, max_, n_] :=
 Module[{nwl},
  nwl = NestWhileList[f, expr, test, m, max];
  Join[nwl, Rest[NestList[f, Last[nwl], n]]]
  ]

In[75]:= myNestWhileList[# + 1 &, 1, False &, 1, 1, 1]

Out[75]= {1, 2}
```

Clearly, It's not a completely general replacement for `NestWhileList`, but it should be easy enough to generalize if necessary.

I've submitted a bug report.

Comment: Thanks Michael -- figured this was just about the simplest way of doing that :)

Comment: No problem, and thanks for pointing it out. You can always email bugs to support@wolfram.com too, if you'd prefer.